# Counting with potency and simplifing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So I have the question: Simplify $(6^{n+4}) / 2^{n+5} \cdot 3^{n+2}$

I tried to write the expresion as $6^{n+4-(2n+7)}/6$, but that is wrong.

So I guess I should factor it out. Perhaps $2^{2} + 2^{n+4}$ / $2^{n+5} \cdot 3^{n+2}$

Can you show me how to expand this expresion?

Comment: HINT:
$6=2\cdot3, 6^{n+4}=(2\cdot3)^{n+4}=2^{n+4}\cdot3^{n+4}$

Comment: Equations do have an equal sign ($=$) somewhere.

Comment: Thanks lab for the solution

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { { 6 }^{ n+4 } }{ { 2 }^{ n+5 }{ 3 }^{ n+2 } } =\frac { \left( 2\cdot 3 \right) ^{ n+4 } }{ { 2 }^{ n+5 }{ 3 }^{ n+2 } } =\frac { { 2 }^{ n+4 }{ 3 }^{ n+4 } }{ { 2 }^{ n+5 }{ 3 }^{ n+2 } } ={ 2 }^{ n+4-n-5 }{ 3 }^{ n+4-n-2 }={ 2 }^{ -1 }{ 3 }^{ 2 }=\frac { 9 }{ 2 } $$